# why doesn't jquery script load in another view asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a website in my _Layout view I added necessary links for examples, jquery, bootstrap and etc... in another view, I want to use "`DataTable`" library but it can't find `jquery` library before itself.in addition, I have added   `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in the end of the _layout view.I have spent a lot of time but can't find any solution for it.

I got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:62)
    at ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:48)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
    at n.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:167)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:537)
    at i (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
```

==========================================

```
@model  IEnumerable<Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "مدیریت کاربران";
}

@*<h2>مدیریت کاربران</h2>*@

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @*<a type="button" class="btn  btn-success btn-flat btn-md" href="@Url.Action("Create","Users")"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>  افزودن کاربر جدید </a>*@
        <a type="button" class="btn  btn-success btn-flat btn-md" href="/users/create/0"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>  افزودن کاربر جدید </a>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">کاربران</h3>
                <div class="box-tools">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                        <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding tablecontainer">

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap direction" id="myDatatable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>UserId</th>
                            <th>UserName </th>
                            <th>FirstName </th>
                            <th>LastName</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>IsActive</th>
                            <th>PhoneNumber</th>
                            <th>Address</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">ویرایش کاربران</h4>

                <div class="modal-body" id="editBody">


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-flat btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> ویرایش کاربر</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts{
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $("#myDatatable").DataTable({

            "ajax":
            {
                "url": '/users/GetUsers',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "UserId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "UserName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "FirstName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "LastName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "IsActive", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "PhoneNumber", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Address", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/users/Edit/' + data + '">Edit</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/users/delete/' + data + '">Delete</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]

        })
        $('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.popup', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            OpenPopup($(this).attr('href'));
        });

        function OpenPopup(pageUrl) {
            var $pageContent = $('<div/>');
            $pageContent.load(pageUrl, function () {

                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('validator');
                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');

            });

            $dialog = $('<div class="popupWindow" style="overflow:auto"></div>')
                .html($pageContent)
                .dialog({
                    draggable: false,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    model: true,
                    title: 'Popup Dialog',
                    height: 550,
                    width: 600,
                    close: function () {
                        $dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                })

            $('.popupWindow').on('submit', '#popupForm', function (e) {
                var url = $('#popupForm')[0].action;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $('#popupForm').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            $dialog.dialog('close');
                            oTable.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    }
                })

                e.preventDefault();
            })

            $dialog.dialog('open');

        }
    });
</script>
}
```

=====================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>پنل مدیریت - دندان پزشکی</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/c7442c63ea.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/morris/morris.css">
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">*@
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery 2.2.0 -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>*@
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>*@
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    @*<script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>*@
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td1my.png)

Comment: @Rise,I got  this error,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:62)
    at ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:48)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
    at n.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:167)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:537)
    at i (jQuery-2.2.0.min.js:2)

Comment: @Rise, but it inherited the layout.so, to ensure, I added this code in another view. Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; but it doesn't have any effect on my view.

Comment: As per your image, if you are having problem, only with data which is showing in your table, then kindly the check whether Model IEnumerable<Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel> is coming properly with data from the controller. Hope it may help you

Comment: @KarthikElumalai, yes exactly I have a problem with my data.in fact, I have used identity for authorization and authorization as you know identity have used "guid" type for the primary key.when I want to fetch data from controller "datatable" had a problem with UserId because UserId is the type of "guid".I don't know do you have any solution for me, please?

Comment: @KarthikElumalai, I 'm creating a new question about my problem.if you have any solution. please give me in the new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163155/how-to-load-data-into-datatable-that-using-guid-primary-key

Comment: @rayan good that your problem was identified correctly and i have provided  an answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45179919/3397630 . hope it will give you some idea and solve your problem  thanks

Answer (score 0):

you'r view must inherit the `_Layout`
you can specify the inheriting in view page with below code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewBag.Title = "مدیریت کاربران";
}
```

or you can create `_ViewStart.cshtml` in `View` folder with below content:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

the deference is in first approach you cant set the diffrent layout for each view page but in second approach you set the layout for all view page in view folder.

and after that you need `@RenderBody()` in `_Layout.cshtml` were you'r view must show

Comment: I have _viewStart.cshtml but I have a just problem with my table.in fact, my table used ajax request for receiving data I have used "datatable" and it needs jquery library before itself. I don't have any problem with my view.i have a problem with my table.

Comment: please you watch this picture i.stack.imgur.com/Td1my.png my view is rendered but I have a problem with my table.

Comment: @rayan check it with jquery1.10+